# WCF Data serialization

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization

Working with WCF how it should modify this DataContract or code:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class listaActos
Private _codigoActo As List(Of String)

<DataMember(IsRequired:=True)>
Public Property codigoActo() As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _codigoActo
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
        _codigoActo = value
    End Set
End Property   ...
```

which generates following response xml when serializing:

```
 <a:listaActos>
     <a:codigoActo xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <b:string>01672</b:string>
     </a:codigoActo>  </a:listaActos>
```

but I want to bo as follows:

```
<a:listaActos>
     <a:codigoActo>01672</a:codigoActo>
     <a:codigoActo>01673</a:codigoActo>
     <a:codigoActo>01674</a:codigoActo></a:listaActos>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't care exactly how the serialization works. Thats an internal detail of WCF that your application code should not depend upon. Are you trying to consume this service from a non-WCF client? If you are then a simpler serialization might work better for you, such as JSON.

Comment: If you have a specify requirement that you need to have it in the below structure the easiest way would be to generate a sample class from the xml using the xsd.exe tool from vs.net command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class `listaActos` only has the list of `codigoActo` in it, then you can make it a collection type (make it inherit from `List(Of String)`, for example). That will get you the XML shape you want with the `DataContractSerializer`.

If it has more members, then you'll need to use the `XmlSerializer`, and define the class as such.

The code below shows the list option.

```
Public Class StackOverflow_10554490
    <CollectionDataContract(Name:="listaActos", Namespace:="http://my.namespace", ItemName:="codigoActo")> _
    Public Class listaActos
        Inherits List(Of String)
    End Class

    <DataContract(Name:="Root", Namespace:="http://my.namespace")> _
    Public Class Root
        <DataMember()> _
        Public Property listaActos As listaActos
    End Class

    Public Shared Sub Test()
        Dim list As listaActos = New listaActos()
        list.Add("01672")
        list.Add("01673")
        list.Add("01674")
        Dim root = New Root With {.listaActos = list}
        Dim dcs = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(Root))
        Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, root)
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: .. where is the element <codigoActo> ?

Comment: The `ItemName` property of the `CollectionDataContract` attribute.

Comment: The ItemName property of the CollectionDataContract attribute is "listaActos".. could be the DataContract Name:="listaActos" and the CollectionDataContract Name="codigoActo" for this porpouse and displayed exactly the xml output expected?

Comment: If you want the item name to be 'codigoActo' as you have in your question, then `ItemName` must be set to this. The code I have displays the same XML you have (it doesn't have the "a" prefix, but the elements are in the correct namespace).